# Google query beyond 2048 char limit

Tags: google-search

Is there any way to fire a large Google query (eg: multiple search terms, OR separated multiple site or other keywords) the normal limit seems to be 2048 chars. Does Google CSE API or any other API's allow me to make a query beyond that limit?

Comment: just out of curiosity, why do you need a 2000+ char length query string?

Comment: I need to pass in a custom list of links to search for using SITE keywords

Answer (score 0):

You can do post request instead of get. Then you will get 10k limit.
https://support.google.com/gsa/answer/4411411#requests